# Python RegEx check string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

im trying to set correct version on output.
I have this possible strings:

- 0.0.4.1 # 1.
- 7.51.4.1 # 2.
- 0.1.4.1 # 3.

and i need to check, if the "0." is on the start (to set output without 0. or 0.0.)

Output 1. will have just **"4.1"**, 2. gonna stay the **same** and 3. will be **1.4.1**

Im trying to set correct expresion like `^([0\.]{1})([.\d]{3})+$` but even if i use {1} quantifier (to just one "0.") it doesnt work correctly.

Anyone with some clue?

Comment: `re.sub(r'^(0+\.?){1,}', '', version)` [`^(0+\.?){1,}`](https://regex101.com/r/SMyb2q/1)

Comment: ``version.lstrip('0.')`` should do without worrying about regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there should be 4 digit parts with 3 dots, you can first assert the format using a positive lookahead.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^(?=\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)0+\.(?:0+\.)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 4 digit parts with 3 dots
- `0+\.` match 1+ zeroes and `.`
- `(?:0+\.)*` Optionally repeat matching 1+ zeroes and `.`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uoaerq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/08WcUC)

Example

```
import re
strings = ["0.0.4.1", "7.51.4.1", "0.1.4.1", "001", "0.1", ".0.1", "0.0.0.0", "0.1.2.3.4.5"]
pattern = r"^(?=\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)0+\.(?:0+\.)*"
for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, "", s))
```

Output

```
4.1
7.51.4.1
1.4.1
001
0.1
.0.1
0
0.1.2.3.4.5
```

---

Other options might be matching zeroes and a `.` at the start, and then repeatedly zeroes and a dot.

```
^0+\.(?:0+\.)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4bkwXc/1)

Or a broader pattern to match all leading dots and zeroes:

```
^0+\.[.0]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/enilQu/1)

Comment: the https://regex101.com/ is awesome! Dont see that one yet, thank a lot

Comment: it's working like charm, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
texts = ['0.0.4.1','7.51.4.1','0.1.4.1']
for text in texts:
    m = re.fullmatch(r'(?:0+\.)*(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)', text)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
# => 4.1
#    7.51.4.1
#    1.4.1
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zZJb7j). *NOTE*: [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) requires the full string match, so no need specifying the `^` and `$` anchors.

*NOTE 2*: If you do not want to match anything in `0.0.0.0` add the `if m.group(1).replace('0',''):` check before returning the value, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/YelFNg).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTNggz/1) meaning

- `(?:0+\.)*` - zero or  more occurrences of one or more `0`s and a dot
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then zero or more repetitions of a dot and one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple regex:
`^[0\.]+`

https://regex101.com/r/zUKutI/1/